# Unbalanced voltage 12 V batteries during charging with 24 V solar MPPT

Tags: batteries, battery-charging

I have two 12 V batteries connected in series. DC24MF HANKOOK 80 Ah.
They were both 12.8 V before installing them.

But during charge with my 24 V epever MPPT TRIRON, one goes to 14.9 and the other 14.4.
(I can hear one of them boiling louder)
What's wrong?

By connecting the system in 12 V (only one battery) the MPPT rise the voltage up to maximum 14.64 V.

Comment: Did you buy good quality batteries from a reputable seller? Does it say in the battery manual that they are suitable for series use with no balancing?

Comment: @Justme https://www.amazon.fr/Hankook-Batterie-Profonde-Cycle-Loisirs/dp/B011CLGIZ6 It was about 80 euros each

Comment: Difference in capacity between them, probably due to wear. You need to either replace the bad one (or both) or add external balancing.

Comment: @winny I bought them at the same time... They also have the same "serial numbers". I actually have 4 (2 older but same battery, different serial number, I will ignore them for now, but they have the same problem). I'm now charging one to full capacity with my MPPT 12v (cell balancing maybe ?) until charging goes to 1w (For now still charging 11w, slowly decreasing), and will do the same with the other one. Can it fix my problem ?

Comment: Worth a try, but unlikely. Can you adjust down the voltage on your MPPT by 0.3 V or so? It would give you some more life of the system but once a battery starts to degrade in a series system, it will just be punished more and more as time goes on by constant over- and undercharging. A huge Zener diode comes to mind too.

Comment: @winny Not sure what do you mean, charging at 14.3v/28.6 ? Now it's all the default numbers, charging 11w 14.54v. Actually, i already "fixed" this problem when I had 4 batteries. (They failed miserably the same way when connected 2 series 2 parallel, 2 overvoltage, 2 undervoltage) I "fixed" it by connecting in parallel 2 first and then series instead. All voltage were similar across the board, but I had sudden drop of voltage and MPPT not happy at all, sometimes STOP charging for 10 minutes in the middle of the day. (cut 3 or 4 times per day, often when battery bank was "full")

Comment: Amazon aren't a reputable seller of batteries. Where's the data sheet? Where's the quality assurance?

Comment: _”charging at 14.3v/28.6”_ Yes, exactly so.

Comment: @Andyaka I'm just a humble solar hobbyist, buying his first batteries. (2 years ago)

Comment: @winny I could do that, but letting the batteries running like this is scary. What if the gaps keeps growing and one battery explode or something...

Comment: My biggest issue is that my Inverter is 24v so.... I need at least 2 of these batteries running together...

Comment: Should I buy something like that : https://www.ebay.fr/itm/275055321766 And... can it be used for 24v with 2 in series too ? (They talk about 48v for 4x12v batteries)

Comment: Good that you are considering safety. Series connected batteries is always a challenge. The gap _will_ grow between them.

Comment: Your total battery charge voltage is too high. (14.9+14.4)/2 = 14.65V average. Boost charging to about 14.4V at 12V terminated or reduced to float-voltage when current drops to a specified level is in order.  If your charger is not reducing the voltage to float voltage after a designed period then something is wrong. With 2 cells in series and 14.65V x 2 applied, if imbalance occurs one battery will be driven dangerously high, as you are seeing. ...

Comment: Battery university has much good information on lead acid charging. [This](https://batteryuniversity.com/article/bu-403-charging-lead-acid) should be a good starting point.

Answer (score 2):

The two batteries are at a different SoC (State of Charge). Luckily, lead-acid batteries can be balanced through a prolonged charging cycle, which is exactly what you are doing. The battery that is the least charged continues to charge. The battery that is the most charged is converting that same current into heat and into generating hydrogen. As the [HANKOOK DC24MF](https://www.hankook-atlasbx.com/en/product/leisure/dc.do) is a maintenance-free battery, they will vent hydrogen.

If you wish to solve it in a way that doesn't involve hydrogen generation, do the following:

1. Disconnect both batteries
2. Connect them directly in parallel (+ to +)
3. Wait overnight for them to balance each other naturally
4. Disconnect them
5. Reconnect them in series in the system

Comment: "Maintenance-free" batteries certainly do vent. [These batteries are not AGM](https://cdn.hankook-atlasbx.com/static/battery/en/HANKOOK_AtlasBX_small(final).pdf) (look up the DC type "leisure" batteries here). They're just normal flooded batteries but they miss the caps needed to refill them. Hence "maintenance free".

Comment: You're right., Brain fart. I corrected it. Thank you. Other than that, do you agree?

Comment: Thx for the answer, but it didn't work. Even the two batteries with the same brand, same Ah, same serial number.... They still have 0.4v difference between the two when charging. (Despite having the exact same voltage at rest.) I bought a victron "battery balancer" to see if this will help to fix all my problems.

Comment: _(Despite having the exact same voltage at rest.)_ AH! That is a key piece of information! If you had said that, I would have given you a different answer. Add this crucial data in your original question and I will tell you what the problem is.

Comment: @DavideAndrea it already was. "They were both 12.8 V before installing them."

Comment: _before installing them_: that means before charging. That's different from saying what the voltage is after you turn off the charger. What is the voltage after you turn off the charger and let them rest for one hour? Same voltage? Different? By how much?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your additional information:

> Even the two batteries with the same brand, same Ah, same serial number.... They still have 0.4v difference between the two when charging. (Despite having the exact same voltage at rest.)

Then the answer is that the two batteries have different equivalent internal series resistance, at least during charging. That may or may not be a problem. If they also have different resistance during discharging, one of them will sag more than the other, will heat-up more, and won't last as long.